Having trouble hosting a React App on Github Pages
I was wondering if I could get some help on hosting a project I've been doing. The repository is here: https://github.com/lazipops/Pokepedia
My problem is hosting it on Github Pages. My project works locally with no problem but when I host it on Github Pages, all I see is a blank screen and in the console it says "main.tsx:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."
Here's what I see when I host my repo on Github pages enter image description here
enter image description here
My project is also a React app if that helps. What am I doing wrong?
I'm expecting to host it on Github pages

Have you tried any solutions from the following github community thread: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/61532

You may refer to the guidelines provided here to host it on GitHub Pages: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages

Try to use Vercel to host your react app, which will be way easier than GitHub pages. as to my knowledge Github pages requires you to host static websites and doesn't support react. Which you can still overcome if you exported your build as static you can search how to configure react to do this.
Also you uploaded node_modules to your GitGhub repository. delete them and edit your .gitignore to just

node_modules

you don't need to add each module in the file.

I tried hosting with Vercel but it can't execute npm run build
